# EF CodeFirst mapping enum with custom value mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, ef-code-first

I need to create an application that is compatible with various legacy database systems.
So, the database exists, but I still want to use code first to be independent from whatever database is used as datastore. For each deployment, I intend to create a "mapping" library containing the correct FluentAPI mappings of the entities to the database.

I'm using EF6.

I don't want code first to alter anything in the database structure automagically, so I use

```
Database.SetInitializer<mycontext>(null);
```

Now I'm stuck on following issue:

my code defines an enum Gender, which is used as a property in the Person entity

```
public enum Gender
{
    M = 1,
    F = 2
}
```

However, in one of the legacy databases, the values are the other way around. The table "Gender" exists, and the lookup data in that table is ID 1 = female, ID 2 = male.
The Person table has a "FK Gender ID" column.

How would I configure through Fluent API the mapping of the Gender property of my Person entity, to the Person table in the legacy database table.

```
modelbuilder.Entity<Person>()
.Property(c => c.Gender)
.HasColumnName("FK Gender ID") //--> and how to "inverse" these values here ?
```

Is this possible with Fluent API, and if not, is there a workaround ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that something you are trying to do is possible. For simplicity you should consider changing your code to match what you have in your database. If you cannot do that here is what you can do. Define an enum type (something like `GenderDb` or something). Ideally no one should even see this enum. Then create private properties of `GenderDb` type and map them to database columns (I believe in EF you can [map columns to private properties](http://romiller.com/2012/10/01/mapping-to-private-properties-with-code-first/)). Again the properties are private so that no one can see them. Then add public properties of the `Gender` type on the entities that have the private `GenderDb` properties. The public properties should be configured as not mapped/ignored. Now implement the setter and the getter of the public properties so that it converts the value accordingly (i.e. setter converts the `Gender` enum to `GenderDb` and sets the private property, getter reads the private property and converts `GenderDb` to `Gender`).

(Yes you could get away with just one enum type if you like to receive phone calls at 2 am)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I hoped some sort of function would exist in the EF mapping API to tackle this, but thanks for giving info about a possible workaround